# Error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que estoy usando typescript, pero tengo un problema al transformar esto al javascript y querer correrlo. al querer correr el arhivo .js tengo este problema

```sh
Error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true
   },
   "exclude": ["node_modules"],
   "include": ["src"]
}
```

intente soluciones que me decian que cambiara el target o el lib pero esto hace que deje de funcionar mi proyecto arrancando desde typescript.
para transpilar uso

```
tsc
```

mi code en server.ts es

```js
import {App} from './app';
import { createConnection,Connection,getConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";
import 'reflect-metadata';

import 'dotenv/config';

import { GrandTotalController } from './apiServices/accounting/grandtotal/grandtotal.controller';


import { AuthController } from './apiServices/auth/auth.controller';
import {validateEnv} from './utils/validateEnv';
import { OrganizationController } from './apiServices/organization/organization.controller';


validateEnv();

createConnection()
.then(async connection=>{
    const app = new App([
        new GrandTotalController(),
        new AuthController(),
        new OrganizationController(),
        // new AuthenticationController,
        //                 new AccountMonthController
                    ],
        5000);
    await app.listen();
}).catch(error=>{
    console.log(`Error ${error}`.red);
});
```

cualquier consejo se les agradece

Answer (score 1):

Puedes instalar ts-node
npm i -D ts-node y en el start le pones

```
“start”:”ts-node ./ruta-al-código”
```

Si gustas puedes ver mis tutorial es en YouTube de cómo hacer un servidor con express webpack y typescript
https://youtu.be/oIRPbAnxo1s

Comment: Entonces esto solucionaria el error: `Error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module ` que tiene el OP?

Comment: esto no sirvio para mi tengo el siguiente output  en el terminal ``` Error RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "GrandTotal" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?```

Comment: No. De hecho si sirvió. Tu error original era cannot use import outside of a module, con lo de ts-node tu código si se compiló, pero ahora tienes otro problema con sequelize